how to access restriction by IP address (svn)
I want to restrict access to svn repository by ip address.
Added "require ip xx.xx.xx.xx/24" to [repository]conf/svnserve.conf
But used Tortoisesvn Repository Browser to see the repository, it show Unable to connect to a repository at URL Erroe while parsing config file line 8(added line):Option must end with ':' or '='.
So added ':' to the line, cant restrict access to the repository.
whats wrong?
Added "require ip xx.xx.xx.xx/24" to [repository]conf/svnserve.conf
But used Tortoisesvn Repository Browser to see the repository, it show Unable to connect to a repository at URL Erroe while parsing config file line 8(added line):Option must end with ':' or '='.
So added ':' to the line, cant restrict access to svn repository.

You seem to confuse svnserve with Apache httpd.
These are two different programs, both of which can serve a Subversion repository.
See svnserve, a Custom Server and httpd, the Apache HTTP Server in the Red Bean Book.
Svnserve offers a very lightweight configuration file, summarized in man svnserve.conf.
Notably, there's no require ip variable or anything like it.
If there were, the syntax would be something like foo = xx.xx.xx.xx/24 (note the equals sign between the variable name and the value).
The Require directive is part of httpd's configuration as explained in Apache: Restrict access to specific source IP inside virtual host

is there any way?

@shs144220shs sorry for the late reply. Well, if you want the features of httpd, you have to use it. With svnserve, there's no way to restrict by IP address.
